# Conditional Expectation Multivariate Normal

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Let $(X1, X2, X3) $ be multivariate normally distributed. I want to prove that 
$$E(X1|X2,X3)=E(X_1|X_2)+\Sigma_{X_1X_3}\Sigma_{X_3 X_3}^{-1}X_3$$ I think one way of getting there is using with $Y=(X_2, X_3)$ that $$E(X_1|Y)=\mu_x+\Sigma_{X_1Y}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}(Y-\mu_Y)$$ and then using the formula for block matrix inversion for $\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}$ but this seems very tedious. Is there a more elegant way to prove this?

**Edit**
We need $E(X_3)=0$ and $\Sigma_{X_2 X_3}=0$, then the "block inversion" is trivial and the result follow immediately.

Comment: 1) If your formula is true then $EX_3=0$. You parobbaly want to assume that the each of the $X_i$'s has mean $0$.

Comment: 2) As far as I can see inverting a $2\times 2$ matrix seems necessary to prove this.

Comment: In fact, I was missing multiple conditions, very silly. We need $E(X_3)=0$ and $\Sigma_{X_2 X_3}=0$. Then the inversion becomes very simple.