# The conditional distribution of singular multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let$\begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf X\\
\mathbf Y
\end{bmatrix}\sim N(
\begin{bmatrix} 
\mathbf \mu_X\\
\mathbf \mu_Y
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 
 \Sigma_{XX} & \Sigma_{XY}\\
 \Sigma_{YX} & \Sigma_{YY}
\end{bmatrix})$. If $\Sigma_{XX}$ is full rank, it is easy to show that (we can find that the covariance between $\mathbf Y - \Sigma_{YX}\Sigma_{XX}^{-1}\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf X$ is zero)
$$
\mathbf Y|\mathbf X \sim N(\mu_Y+\Sigma_{YX}\Sigma^{-1}_{XX}(\mathbf X-\mu_X),\Sigma_{YY}-\Sigma_{YX}\Sigma^{-1}_{XX}\Sigma_{XY})
$$
But if $\Sigma_{XX}$ is not full rank, what is the distribution of $\mathbf Y|\mathbf X$? (Here, the inverse of $\Sigma_{XX}$ does not exist, so the above method can not be used.)

Comment: The same result holds with $\Sigma^{-1}_{XX}$ replaced by a generalized inverse $\Sigma^{-}_{XX}$.

Comment: How to obtain the result? If $\Sigma_{XX}^{-1}$ is replaced by $\Sigma_{XX}^-$, then the covariance between $\mathbf Y - \Sigma_{YX}\Sigma_{XX}^{-}\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf X$ is not zero. I don't know obtain the result.

Comment: They are still uncorrelated. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/270934/119261, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3595992/321264.